# LDAP Search String Exclude

Tags: php, ldap, ldap-query

I am rewriting a few PowerShell scripts to work in PHP and this one has me stuck. I need to get a list of computers, but exclude those with -NEW and -OLD. Below is how I would think to do it, but when I try that I get `ldap_search(): Search: Bad search filter` as an error.

`$LDAP_Search_String = "(&(objectClass=computer)(name=NFDW*)(!name=NFDW*-NEW)(!name=NFDW*-OLD))";`

If I remove `(!name=NFDW*-NEW)(!name=NFDW*-OLD)` from the query, it works fine.

Additional Info:
I have tried `(&(objectClass=computer)(name=NFDW*)(|(!name=NFDW*-NEW)(!name=NFDW*-OLD)))` as well as suggested by a deleted answer and the same result of a Bad search filter.

Comment: try adding parenthesis around your `!` i.e. `(!(name=NFDW*-NEW))(!(name=NFDW*-OLD))`

Comment: @FuzzyTree Well there we go. Please put that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding parenthesis around your ! i.e. `(!(name=NFDW*-NEW))(!(name=NFDW*-OLD))`